# sed: get two patterns, one before other in line

Tags: regex, bash, unix

I have a file ´corpus.txt´ and I'm trying to get only two pattern; one is specific `<PLANET>` and other is any word. Actually, I need that sed search the pattern in whole text. I simply can't do it, I've read many works about what I am doing but I can't concatenate theses sed's codes.

An example corpus.txt is:

`aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbaabb
and was searching through them in 1846 the German astronomer <NAME> discovers <PLANET> and it's notable for its active and visible weather patterns
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbsssddd
in 1846 a German astronomer discovers <PLANET> and it's slightly more massive than its near-twin Uranus
bbbbffaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`

<sup>*For the record, there are 5 lines of input; the search does not need to span lines.*</sup>

I need the output:

`<NAME> discovers <PLANET>
astronomer discovers <PLANET>`

I am trying: `s/\([^ ]*\) \(discovers <PLANET>\).*/\1 \2/g`

I know the `sed` code is wrong, but it is all I've got by myself. If I pass the result with Unix's pipe, I get all lines in the text and the lines that contains the patterns are filtered, like this:

`aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbaabb
<NAME> discovers <PLANET> and its notable for its active and visible weather patterns
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbsssddd
astronomer discovers <PLANET> and it's slightly more massive than its near-twin Uranus
bbbbffaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`

Comment: I don't understand your requirements. Do you need to find the previous non-blank substring before the word `discovers` if the next non-blank substring is `<PLANET>`?

Comment: Not necessary. I only need find _any word_ before the pattern `discovers <PLANET>`

Comment: Ok, for the string `"Marcel :;#?? discovers <PLANET>"`, you want to catch `Marcel`?

Comment: Actually in this case I want to catch the substring `:;#??`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to fix.

1. First, you want to suppress the default 'print the line' action, which is done with the `-n` option.
2. Then you want to replace the whole input line for matches with just the three words and print it.

Hence, you get:

```
sed -n 's/.* \([^ ]\{1,\} discovers <PLANET>\).*/\1/p'
```

Comment: It doesnt works. if I use `sed -n` and pass the resul to a new file, this new file comes empty.

Comment: Curious; I developed/tested the code on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04), and it worked OK there.  I've just tested it on Mac OS X 10.9.4, copying the data and script verbatim and it worked correct there too, as I expected.  So, we have to find out why it didn't work for you.  Which platform are you working on?  Did you copy the code verbatim (copy'n'paste) or did you retype the code? I suppose I might need to check which shell you're using, but it would have to be rather obscure for it to break this (the command would work with POSIX-like or C-shell-like shells).

Comment: Sorry Jonathan, now it's works, thank you. But the result back only the caracter before the pattern, like `> discovers <PLANET> `.

Comment: That sounds as if you omitted the comma after the 1 in the braces {}.

Comment: I miss a single space in the expression. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

**Another Command-Line Option: perl one-liner**

This is a great job for a Perl one-liner. (If anyone can tell me why perl is worse than x, y or z, they can have the leftovers from my breakfast.)

```
perl -0777 -ne 'while($_=~ m/\S+ discovers <PLANET>/g){print "$&\n";}' yourfile
```

**Explanation**

- `\S+` matches any char that is not a whitespace char
- `discovers <PLANET>` matches literals
- the `g` flag finds all matches

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't know how Pearl works and top of this there is the challenge of to explain the every lineof my code. But I'll save your answer for future.

Comment: Just out of curiosity/laziness, what is the significance of `-0777`?  I've never needed to use it (or not known that I would benefit from using it).

Comment: This line was just something you can paste into your shell command-line, and it does the job. But no problem if that doesn't work for you, just showing another option. :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It sets an undefined delimiter, which allows you to slurp the whole file into `$_` (otherwise `-n` will feed you the file line by line) Also see [this man page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) and search `0777`

Comment: OK; reasonable for files under a few megabytes; not necessarily such a good idea for files of multiple gigabytes.  One advantage of the Perl solution is that if the magic words appear several times on a line, then you can get all the outputs for the line instead of just one.